# symfony: "clean-model-files" for Propel?

Tags: symfony1, propel

when i try `build-all-load` i'm getting errors about models that
doesn't exist any more in my schema. I know in doctrine i can use
`clean-model-files` but in propel?

This is the error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(lib/model/om/BaseSedii18n.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/javier/Aptana_Studio_Workspace/cashgold/lib/model/Sedii18n.php on line 3
```

Javier

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's no similar task in propel.

You could try a bash script below. **Backup your code first**. I assume you're some kind of version control system.

This should list files causing your problems:

```
./symfony s 2>&1 | grep "failed to open stream" | sed -e 's/.*directory in \([^ ]\+\/lib\/model\/[^ ]\+\).*/\1/' | sort -u
```

Remove all those files with (you'll be asked before deleting each file):

```
rm -i $(./symfony s 2>&1 | grep "failed to open stream" | sed -e 's/.*directory in \([^ ]\+\/lib\/model\/[^ ]\+\).*/\1/' | sort -u)
```